# What would be the the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PMT()

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to create a JavaScript form that does the same calculation as this `=PMT()` function.

```
mortgage = 220000
rate= 4.75%
term = 30
```

The example formula I have is `=PMT(4.75%/12,30*12,220000*-1)`

What would be the equation for this function? I tried to look up this function but it doesn't explain it very well.

Comment: See also: https://www.quora.com/What-would-be-the-mathematical-equivalent-for-PMT-Excel-Formula-PMT

Comment: See also [*amortization calculator* in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The equation you want is: `P = (Pv*R) / [1 - (1 + R)^(-n)]`

where

- **P**   = Monthly Payment
- **Pv**  = Present Value (starting value of the loan)
- **APR** = Annual Percentage Rate
- **R**   = Periodic Interest Rate = APR/number of interest periods per year
- **n**   = Total number of interest periods (interest periods per year * number of years)

Using the variables above, the Excel =PMT() function is **=PMT(R,n,Pv)**

So, for your example where:

- rate (APR) = 4.75% (making **R**=4.75%/12 or 0.0475/12)
- mortgage (**Pv**) = 220000
- term (# of years) = 30 (**n**=30*12 with monthly payments)

The equation becomes:

```
P = ((220000 * (0.0475/12)) / (1 - ((1 + (0.0475/12))^(-1 * 30 * 12))))
```

Or, with the original equation shown directly below it for comparison:

```
P = ((220000 * (0.0475/12)) / (1 - ((1 + (0.0475/12))^(-1 * 30 * 12))))
P =  (  Pv   *     R      ) / (1 - ( 1 +       R    )^(     -n     )
```

Comment: Which, if anyone is checking, equals $1,147.62416.

Comment: How can this formula be modified to include a fixed monthly increase in the loan, for example is the loan is a credit card and the user spends $50 per month on the card?