# Need mathematical equivalent of this excel formula PMT()

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with the math equivalent for excel formula PMT(). There is an answer @ below thread... BUT nothing is mentioned with regards to the option parameters of PMT() i.e. FV and Type. Can anyone please guide with math equivalent with FV?

[What would be the the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PMT()](https://superuser.com/questions/871404/what-would-be-the-the-mathematical-equivalent-of-this-excel-formula-pmt/1386156#1386156)

Comment: It is not a duplication. Its an extension question which is not answered in that post. Please read question FULLY before commenting.I am a new member and webpage is not allowing me to post comment on that existing question.

Comment: This kind of question seem to better suited for [financially literate](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) community rather than [computer enthusiasts](https://superuser.com/tour)..  || Just in case it had been answered the OP should share the answer here or optionally close it.  Good luck. ( :

Comment: This is actually for an IT project; need to develop a solution equivalent to Excel's PMT ()

Comment: I have figured it out... posting here to help others:       PMT = r / ((1 + r)^N - 1) * (pv * (1 + r)^N - fv)    

 r = Annual Interest rate/100/ Total Number of payments in whole term
 N = Total number of payments in whole term
 PV = Loan Amount
 FV = future Value/Residual Value

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out... here is how FV or Residual Value (RV) will be added to the mix...

```
P = r / ((1 + r)^N - 1) * (pv * (1 + r)^N - fv)
```

- P = Monthly Payment
- PV = Present Value (starting value of the loan)
- APR = Annual Percentage Rate
- r = Periodic Interest Rate = APR/number of interest periods per year
- N = Total number of interest periods (interest periods per year * number of years)

Comment: can confirm this is true. see here for the derivation: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225502/8988

Comment: This absolutely saved my bacon. I scoured for so long trying to find a formula that factored in future value. Thank you!!!