# Looking for the mathematical equiv of the PMT function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a question which I am analysing for a university paper, which is asking for the monthly payment on an investment after 1 year.

I have plugged the values into Excel and have found the payment that correlates to the correct answer for this question, but to better understand the question I want to manually calculate the payment.

I have tried pmt formulas from other threads but they just do not bring up the correct answer and I am seriously struggling to understand why.

The last formula i tried was: PMT = (Pv * R)/(1-(1+R)^-n)

My values are

Pv = 492,800

Period is monthly over 1 year = 1x12 = 12

Rate: 4.32% per annum compounded monthly, so 0.36% monthly, or 0.0036

Fv = 480242.25 (after 1 year)

PMT= ?

The payment value is supposed to be $2800, but besides Excel, I have been unable to answer the question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the the mathematical equivalent of this excel formula? =PMT()](https://superuser.com/questions/871404/what-would-be-the-the-mathematical-equivalent-of-this-excel-formula-pmt)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Excel spreadsheet that does this calculation.

Here is the procedure:

1. Compute the NPV of the FV of the Investment (`=480242.25`)

   `=NPV(Rate / Period, FV_of_Investment)`

   `=$459,973.21`
2. Compute the difference between this NPV and the PV of the investment. This tells us the present value of the level payments over the first year. This is the key insight of how to perform this calculation.

   `=PV_of_Investment - Value_Today_of_FV_at_1_year`

   `=$32,826.79`
3. Use the formula you mentioned above to find the level payments associated with this difference

   `=Present_Value_of_Level_Payments * (Rate / Period) / (1 - (1 / (1 + Rate/Period) ^ Period))`

   `=$2,800.00`

Writing this as one big formula, you get:

`= (NPV(Rate / Period, FV_of_Investment) - PV_of_Investment) * ((Rate / Period) / (1 - (1 / (1 + Rate/Period) ^ Period)))`

I used [FormulaChop](https://formulachop.com/) (Full disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop) to generate these formulas. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMBk7.png) of its output when run on the big formula.

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07898135314185353932) is a link to the spreadsheet in the screenshot.